# Proving the minimal entropy of Dilithium-QROM?

Tags: entropy, random-oracle-model, quantum-cryptography, zero-knowledge, dilithium

I am working with the securit yof CRYSTAL's Dilithium signature in the QROM. I am working with [Kiltz et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/916.pdf)'s approach through lossy ID-schemes and looking at the proof of minimal entropy for the $DFS[ID, H, PRF]$ derived Dilithium-QROM signature. Unfortunately, I am not able to see how the proof of the lemma flows, nor understand what is beeing done and why it is "ok" to make the claims that are made... I was hoping someone here would be able to help me.

The definition of minimal entropy I am working with:

[image]

and the lemma with proof I can't seem to understand:

[image]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you!